# How to enable CORS on Rails and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building an API which has CORS enabled like so (Its in dev mode so the rules are quite lax):

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors", :debug => true, :logger => (-> { Rails.logger }) do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '/cors',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:post],
      :credentials => true,
      :max_age => 0

    resource '*',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :head],
      :max_age => 0
  end
end
```

And the client is consuming the API fine, no problem. Now I'm trying to add file upload via Carrierwave, Fog and S3. In my config I've got the following:

Whenever I add the following config:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     'xxx',                        # required
    aws_secret_access_key: 'yyy',                        # required
    region:                'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    host:                  's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    endpoint:              'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                          # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                        # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

When without any contact with S3, my API/CORS stops working. So I thought the problem was the CORS on my S3 bucket.

So I've added the following CORS on the bucket:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
   <CORSRule>
     <AllowedOrigin>MYIP</AllowedOrigin>

     <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>

     <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
```

I still get the CORS blocking the API calls. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem and exposing Header served the purpose for me.Below is the edited version of your code containing required change.

```
<CORSConfiguration>
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>MYIP</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Please make sure that in <AllowedOrigin> tag you are using proper format.
Sample for my local development server is :
I used MYIP = http://localhost:3000 
This is working fine for me, please recheck the format and let me know if this is working for you.Please confirm that your issue here is due to CORS i.e Cross origin request.